# high resolution timer in android for metronome

Tags: java, android, timer

I'm trying to create a metronome for Android, and I wrote this code to play a beep at 300BPM using a SoundPool, but it tends to skip beats sometimes and creates lag. I have researched, and all of the answers I have found don't solve my issue. This especially happens when I try to speed up the bpm count or use eighth notes instead of quarter (double time). Can someone guide me in the right direction of making this as accurate as possible? Delay/beat-skipping is **not acceptible**. Thanks!!

```
     final SoundPool sndPool = new SoundPool(3, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
     final int sndHigh = sndPool.load(this, R.raw.high, 1);
     setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
     Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable(){
          public void run() {
            while(true){
                sndPool.play(sndHigh, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);
                //Log.d("asd", "beep");
                LockSupport.parkNanos(((240000/300)/4)*1000000); //300bpm
            }
          }
     });
     th.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
     th.start();
```

Comment: 300 BPM? Are you sure that's what you really need?

Comment: yup. but think 150BPM at eighth notes. that would be equal to 300. so it needs to go way faster. up to sixtuplets.

Comment: You mentioned "metronome" in the question. As a musician (whose father was a music teacher) I was taught that a metronome is "usually" meant to measure the quarter-note (although that may vary slightly based on the composition). In reality, at 150bpm for something like D'n'B, the drummer may actually be hitting the drums 300 times per minute but they shouldn't need to hear 300 beeps per minute from a metronome. In reality a good drummer should be able to listen to a 75bpm metronome (for example) and still co-ordinate 300 drum beats per minute.

Comment: thanks, but that's not what im looking for. ive been in college studying music theory for a few years now. could you provide anything half useful perhaps?

Comment: **"could you provide anything half useful perhaps?"** - Not really. I suspect the problem may well be hardware latency. The only thing I would suggest would be a longer sound clip. For example record a 4-beat bar with perhaps a down-beat, e.g., BEEP...beep...beep...beep. Use that as the sound clip and instead of looping the `SoundPool` 300 times a minute you can loop it at 75 times a minute. Each loop will play 4 beats but it might reduce the load on the sound hardware and software if it only needs to restart the loop every 800ms instead of every 200ms. Continued in next comment...

Comment: You could use different sound clips for different time signatures that would scale by speed - 3/4, 6/8 etc etc. Each clip wouldn't take much space if the sounds are just a sequence of beeps or clicks.

Comment: That'd work.. but you see my time signature is dynamic so the users have full control over it. i dont really want to limit the user by supplying a certain amount of time signature choices.. however, apk size doesn't really matter to me right now, so that's good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is not to use a timer or SoundPool at all.  Instead use a low-level AudioTrack that you manage continuously.  You will have to synthesize the beep or click or whatever by inserting the appropriate samples into the AudioTrack at the proper point in the buffer.  Just Google AudioTrack and look for samples on how it is used.