# Making precise android metronome

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app for Android and in it's core it has a metronome.
I need to produce sounds precisly in beat. And every 2nd sound is delayed for "swing" percentage of interval.
My current code looks like this:

```
public void play() {
    mainCountHandler.postDelayed(mainClick, 0);
    subCountHandler.postDelayed(subClick, (MILLIS_IN_MINUTE/ (2 * bpm)) * (100 + swing));
}

private Runnable mainClick = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        playSound();
        mainCountHandler.postDelayed(this, MILLIS_IN_MINUTE / bpm);
    }
};

private Runnable subClick = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        playSound();
        subCountHandler.postDelayed(this, MILLIS_IN_MINUTE / bpm);
    }
};

private void  playSound() {
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, SOUND);
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        };
    });

    ++currentBeat;
    if (currentBeat >= beatsCount) {
        if (loop) {
            currentBeat = 0;
        } else {
            stop();
        }
    }
}
```

And this runs terribly inaccuate. I tried **SoundPool** and also creating **MediaPlayer** outside of **playSound** and there's no singnificant changes. 
So is there any modifications or maybe another Android classes that can help me?

Comment: maybe try using a different timer, like ScheduledExecutorService or java.util.Timer

Comment: I agree with @ergonaut - the problem is probably that you're using the Handler of the main (UI) thread to try to time your metronome beats, and there's a lot going on in that thread. Do it all in a new background thread - MediaPlayer doesn't need to be called from the UI thread. You may still have problems, though, since Android is not a real-time system (beware of Garbage Collection).

Comment: Thanks @ergonaut timer really solved the problem.

Comment: Anybody visiting this question, you should be using Android AudioTrack, please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106786/high-resolution-timer-in-android-for-metronome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the most precise metronome that I can achieve looks like this:

```
public void play() {
    mainTimer = new Timer();
    subTimer = new Timer();
    mainTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
    subTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();

    mainTimer.schedule(mainTimerTask, 0, MILLIS_IN_MINUTE / bpm);
    subTimer.schedule(subTimerTask, (300 * (100+swing)) / bpm, MILLIS_IN_MINUTE / bpm);

}

private void  playSound() {
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, SOUND);
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        };
    });
}

class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        playSound();
    }
}
```